# How do I change dynamic column names in MariaDB?

Tags: mariadb

I have created a table using the dynamic columns feature in MariaDB:

```sql
CREATE TABLE items
(id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
 name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 attributes BLOB);

INSERT INTO items (name, attributes) VALUES
('T-shirt', COLUMN_CREATE('color', 'blue', 'size', 'XL', 'price' '30.0'));
```

The dynamic column contains the columns `color`, `size` and `price`. How would I rename, for instance, the column `price` to `amount`, while actually retaining this column's content? I know about `COLUMN_ADD` and `COLUMN_DELETE`, but I haven't seen a *`COLUMN_RENAME`* function. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you would have to use `COLUMN_ADD` then use `COLUMN_DELETE` to re-add the same column data under a different name then delete the previous column name from the dynamic columns.